Is it possible to run VS Code through Firefox?
Can the default runtime executable be changed from Chrome to Firefox and how?

To change the default browser used by VS Code for debugging to Firefox:
you'll need to configure your launch.json file in your project's .vscode folder. This file tells VS Code how to launch and debug your application.
Example:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "firefox",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Firefox",
            "reAttach": true,
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}

